# Using a non clickable MapView

Tags: android, click, android-mapview

For the need of my application, I need a Mapview should act like an ImageView.

The small map that would not have the default behavior (user is not allowed to move it) and I need to launch Google Maps when clicked on it.

I have tried to use code like this:

```
mapView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("geo:<lat>,<long>?q=<lat>,<long>(Label+Name)"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

But it seems that the OnClickListener is never called, and I have not found how to disable the mapview scroll.

Thank for any help.

EDIT:
I already tried to use clickable=false, taht's a good thing, because the map is now "disabled" and user cannot move it, but I an not able to launch GMaps when clicked...

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5716704/1321873

Comment: are you able to stop the mapview scroll ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set `clickable(false)` you can't use `onClick`, when you set `clickable(true)` then `onTouch` will take focus. So, override `onTouch` and then check inside it if your map view is not clickable, and if it is not clickable => start the activity.

Comment: Yeah, well I just saw your question and thought of this on top of my head. Maybe there is a better alternative for this.

Answer (score 2):

to launch Google Maps use onTouchListener because onClickListenere is never called when clicked on mapview. I tried like this :

```
mapView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

where NextActivity is another activity which extends MapActivity.

Comment: Thank a lot, but Carnal was too fast with the same answer

Comment: :-) yes, i'm in a learning stage so little bit hesitant before giving answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to after mapView ready set onClick listener

```
mapView?.getMapAsync {googlemap->

     googlemap. setOnMapClickListener(object : GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener {
         override fun onMapClick(p0: LatLng?) {
            //...
         }

})
```

Answer (score -2):

make `android:clickable="false"` in your xml file can help you

Comment: it works, but I cannot launch Google Maps when the user click on the map after that..

Comment: you can make clickable to false in your map on click listener

Comment: as explained in the question, OnClickListener is never called, with clickable set to true or false, in both cases

Comment: @Waza_Be other solution is to set map click false and put a empty transparent view on top and make that one clickable.

Comment: Doesn't work when I set it in XML. Had to do it programmatically, and it mapView.setClickable(false);
            mapView.setLongClickable(false);